# Prevent editing of the live Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, git

We have developers with development setups, who commit and push to our server running a live website on Visual Studio 2010.

After they push, they RDC into the server, pull in the updated files, include additional files (if necessary) and then build.

Unfortunately, people keep getting mixed up between RDC sessions and keep editing the files on the live server. Is there any way to prevent this? Or is there a better best practice? Thanks.

Comment: ... why do you have VS2010 on your webserver?

Comment: Perhaps this is showing my naivety with a .NET powered website, but what is the alternative? Compiling everything locally and then pushing the compiled site?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command line `mstsc /console /v:servername` or  `mstsc /admin /v:servername` to connect to session 0. This will ensure that all developers who are connecting are connecting to the same session

Comment: So it seems like that would limit the number of people with a remote connection server to one? That might help, but people might inadvertently kick other people off when they try to pull from Git at the same time.